# Font awesome - undefined variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I am getting the error below when compiling assets in Ruby on Rails.

```
Undefined variable: "$fa-css-prefix".
```

The things I have checked:-

- font-awesome-sass gem in gemfile
- font-awesome and font-awesome-sprockets imported
- _variables checked to make sure fa-font-path points to the fonts location
- _variables renamed to _aavariables to try and force this to be the first file processed.

In my application.scss file I have:-

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree ../css
 *= require_tree ../plugins
 *= require_tree ../plugins/font-awesome/scss
 *= require_tree ../plugins/font-awesome/fonts
```

and

```
 @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
 @import "bootstrap";
 @import "font-awesome-sprockets";
 @import "font-awesome";
```

I can get rid of the error temporarily by including an import statement for 'variables' in each of the partials but I would rather fix the cause.

Comment: I'd suspect it has to do with the order of your imports, you could explore that. (something seems to be called before it's been imported).

Comment: [I doub't it has anything to do with font-awesome](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails/issues/157)

Comment: Getting nowhere fast with this other than I am pretty confident it is not processing the font-awseome.scss file. I manually added the appropriate imports into each file and I was able to get past the errors in the font-awesome folder but I then got the same errors in another folder (SASS). I could manually amend these files too but there has to be a reason this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now resolved this issue. It boiled down to the fact that my `require` statement in `application.scss` wasn't referencing the `font-awesome.css` file correctly.

Due to the fact that I have imported a website from `wrap-bootstrap` my assets are in non-standard places and I was incorrectly referencing the font-awesome file.

I corrected the problem by adding this line to application.scss:-

```
*= require font-awesome/css/font-awesome
```

Comment: If you'd like to help other people with this problem in the future (and get upvotes), perhaps you can include the code that worked. And accept your answer as the solution.